# D3 or Raphael for modeling tool?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael, data-visualization, modeling

I'm building a modeling tool that contains 2 sets of sliders -- one set that changes the amount per month payment (at top), and one set that shows user the date their debt is paid off (bottom), effectively so that changes to one can be seen in the other:
[modeling tool http://doufeel.com/model.png](http://doufeel.com/model.png)

I was able to use jQuery UI slider to generate the payment data that creates the line graph at the bottom (using D3) but now I realize that I will probably need to create both sets of sliders in svg using either D3 or Raphael to make this work smoothly. I'm hoping to find someone who has addressed this, perhaps created something similar and might be able to advise on the best approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer for this (unless somebody happens to have implemented exactly what you want). My advice would be to go with the framework that you're more familiar with.

Comment: Well even if someone has had luck creating multi-range slider using svg would be helpful but I was hoping that more devs would have addressed this sort of modeling interactivity in their visualization endeavors.

Answer (score 1):

Need to support older browsers? Use Raphael. If not then D3.